# How to Write Unit Tests for Python Command Line Tool

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am working on getting better code coverage on a Python project, but I've not found a good example on how to test command line tools.  Here is my code:

https://github.com/OpenDataAlex/etlTest/blob/dev/etltest/etlTest.py

I would have included the code in the post, but I didn't just want to post a snippet.  I am building a command line tool that runs other components of the project.

The tests I have written are like the following example:

```
def test_in_file_custom_output_generation_output(self):
    file_param = "-f {0:s}".format(self.in_file)
    output_file = os.path.join(SettingsManager().get_file_location(),
                                   'etltest/samples/output/main/in_file_generation.txt')

    given_result = subprocess.check_output(args=['python', self.process, file_param, "-g"])

    with open(output_file, 'r') as f:
        expected_result = f.read()

    self.assertEqual(given_result, expected_result)

def test_parser_no_args(self):
    #Test if no args returns help options.
    subprocess.check_output(args=['python', self.process], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I'm still new to writing tests for a project like this and would appreciate some guidance.  Should I be using a different testing tool that Python's unittest tool?

Comment: IMO testing command lines feels a bit odd, maybe you should test the library and just trust `argparse`?

Comment: How complicated can a commandline get? I'd hack it until it works and then do other, important things. If you really have a very complex structure (like e.g. a compile with a gazillion options), extract the commandline parser to a separate library (converting from argv to a structure describing the options) and create tests for those, but without actually running applications.

Comment: It's actually a very straightforward bit of code.  I'm just wanting to write tests to ensure that it keeps working as expected :)